# Need to extract data from PCAP, but get only one side of conversation

Tags: tshark

I have captured the data being sent between two computers, and I can see and analyse the traffic properly in WireShark.  I exclude redundant traffic by adding a display filter as "tcp.port == 5000", which shows me all packets coming from the other computer's port 5000, and also showing all traffic outgoing from my  port going to the other computer on port 5000.

I now want to extract the data only of all these packets, and for this I use TShark with the following command-line:

```
tshark -2 -r pcapFile.pcapng -R "tcp.port == 5000" -T fields -e data > datafile.txt
```

However, this only shows me the data that is in packets addressed to 5000 (not the other direction).  I've tried "tcp.srcport == 5000 || tcp.dstport == 5000", but to no avail.  If I open the pcapFile.pcapng with Wireshark I see all data.

How do I need to adjust the commandline so that I get the data from both sides?

Comment: Can you provide a link to your packet capture?

Comment: @Ross If you mean the pcap file in question, sorry I can't - it's contains data I'm not allowed to share

Comment: cmaynard is probably right here - you think that wireshark is showing you a data field, but it's actually something else (and so you need to filter on the right field to see it in tshark).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try this (requires Wireshark >= 2.4.0):

```
tshark -2 -r pcapFile.pcapng -R "tcp.port == 5000 and tcp.payload" -T fields -e tcp.payload > datafile.txt
```

You can find field names, such as `tcp.payload` in Wireshark by selecting the field in the Packet Details pane, which will highlight the corresponding bytes in the Packet Bytes Pane and reveal the field name in the status bar at the bottom of window.

For example, when you select the *"TCP payload (xxx bytes)"* field in the Packet Details pane, the status bar shows, *"The TCP payload of this packet (tcp.payload), xxx bytes"*.  The display filter field you need to use is shown in parentheses.